# Couldn't understand Wscript arguments

Tags: vbscript

I have a line of script but I don't really understand what it means. Can anyone explained it to me ? It's in vbscript

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set InputFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(Wscript.arguments(0))
```

what does the `Wscript.arguments(0)` mean?

Comment: Maybe read the documentation? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z2b05k8s%28v=vs.84%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Answer (score 0):

`0` is 1st argument on command line, `1` is second, etc.